# Is there any method in character class which allow space between two words

Tags: java

I have a scenario in which I am allowing only digits and numbers. 
So, I am using this method from the Character class to have a check for alphanumeric:

```
Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)
```

I am using like this:

```
if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) )
```

But this method is not allowing any space between two words.
e.g.:

```
Test123 - Accepted
Test 123 -- Not Accepted
```

I want in between spaces should also be allowed. Do we have any method in Character or any other Java class which allows alphanumeric as well as space between two words?

Comment: Something like `(!(Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) || Character.isWhitespace(ch))` ...?

Comment: Hi Kelwood, I want special characters also to be allowed, Is there any method from Character class to do same ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using regular expression. You can use [`String.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) to test if a given String matches the given regex. The following line will match a String containing letters and or numbers and or whitespace (which includes space, tab, and new line)

`"Test 123".matches("[\\w\\d\\s]+")`

Comment: I used like this :     if(entry.matches("/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/")) { }                                  This is working fine , any other optimized method you know to do same ?

Comment: I used : if(entry.matches("/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/")) { }                                                      to allow special characters also. It is working fine but do we have any optimized way to do same ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this but you can try regex expressions.

```
String test = "Test 123";
System.out.println(test.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"));
```

This way you check if a character in your string you testing matches any of the characters in square brackets 1 or more times.

Comment: My answer is the same as above, this [\\w\\d\\s]+ is the same way of saying [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+ but shortly.

Comment: Hi Azimut3, I want special characters also to be allowed now ?

Comment: I used like this : if(entry.matches("/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/")) { } This is working fine , any other optimized method you know to do same ?